# generic function return type Pick keys of not known object

Tags: typescript

Suppose we fetch some data thorugh an API that can dynamically compose response structure based on what fields you need in the response.

We have an interface, representing all of the avaliable keys

```js
interface ResponseT {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

I need to design a generic function declaration which receives a list of keys, and which return type is passed type with only keys that are passed to an argument.

Example of usage:

```js
const result = fetch<ResponseT>(["id", "title"]);
//    ^? { id: number; title: string }
```

I have come up with the following declaration:

```js
declare function fetch<
  ResponseT extends object,
  Keys extends keyof ResponseT = keyof ResponseT
>(keys: Keys[]): Pick<ResponseT, Keys>;
```

which results in:

```js
const result = fetch<ResponseT>(["id", "title"]);
//    ^? Pick<ResponseT, keyof ResponseT>
```

This won't work, as type of Keys is set (`Keys extends keyof ResponseT = keyof ResponseT`) and I don't see any way of dynamically setting the type of Keys other than `fetch<ResponseT, "id" | "title">(["id", "title"])`, which is not ideal.

Comment: TypeScript lacks support for *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242). You either need to specify all your type arguments or let the compiler infer all your type arguments.  Workarounds involve currying, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkanpN), or dummy arguments, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wv104m).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find an appropriate dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your answer! Yes, that fully addresses my question. I think I'm gonna go with currying. I do however wonder why is it called "currying".

Comment: I will write up an answer; [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is named after logician Haskell Curry who used the technique extensively, but was actually devised by logician Moses Schönfinkel, but unfortunately the name "Schönfinkelization" has not caught on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript currently lacks support for *partial [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument inference*, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  If you have a call a function that has multiple type parameters, you must either manually specify them all (except for [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)), like `fetch<ResponseT, "id" | "title">(⋯)`); or you must let the compiler infer them all (like `fetch(⋯)`).  It is not possible to manually specify some and have the compiler infer the remainder.  Generic type argument defaults do not serve that purpose, as you've seen (you just get the default, not *inference*).

---

Until and unless anything is implemented there, you'll need to work around it.  The two workarounds I know of are splitting the function into multiple functions (i.e., [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)), or adding a dummy function argument.

The currying approach looks like this:

```
declare function fetch<T extends object>():
    <K extends keyof T>(keys: K[]) => Pick<T, K>;

const result = fetch<ResponseT>()(["id", "title"]);
//    ^?const result: Pick<ResponseT, "id" | "title">
```

Here the function is generic only in `T` the type you'd like to specify, and it takes no function arguments.  Then it returns another function which is generic only in `K`, the type you'd like to have inferred.  (This returned function is not generic in `T`, but will have `T` already specified).  That lets you specify `T` and have `K` inferred, at the cost of an extra intermediary function call.

The dummy parameter approach looks like this:

```
declare function fetch<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    dummyT: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K>;

const result = fetch(null! as ResponseT, ["id", "title"]);
//    ^?const result: Pick<ResponseT, "id" | "title">
```

Here you are adding a dummy parameter to the function of the type `T` you'd normally want to specify manually.  Instead, you call the function with a dummy argument of type `T` and the compiler can therefore *infer* it, along with `K`.  Note that because it's a dummy argument, it only needs to have the right type at compile time; at runtime it will be ignored.  So the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `null! as ResponseT` allows us to pass in `null` at runtime but have it be treated like `ResponseT` at compile time.  There's no error because the type of `null!` is that of a [non-null asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) `null`, which is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), which can be asserted to any type without complaint.  There's no great reason to use `null! as T` over anything else; it's just a relatively concise way to do it.  If you actually *have* a value of type `T` sitting around you could use that instead.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9gFwMoFcYzQCcMIATJAbwFgAoJepAS2BMIDMFkAlaA4KCABVKtBmKakAXEmA4wAIwiEA3KPH0MjDABsI0qBkLMA5qrrqkpaPCMxNaYPsMmzYgL6019K-G0hCyGw4wPD2wEhsEBjwABYAPF7iPLAOAsIQAB4kwKRQSGjyAFYQoQA0iWIA0hAAnnmZ2blIANa1aGxIyXxpSAC8LW0dXalCiQB8ABStddLVdQDaALoAlNIACozwzXHD-EKlSHNQY2aJ8KkYSAFQONqX-ZHR8btpk-MARIyk7wfvmjoQd4rVwMAD0oLEAD0APxIc78S7XW4YdabbYvfYDGrtTq8EaCMaecz0eEGJCwEqMNg1ACC2m0fQiUViOzxe0Evy+7yQAB8kH8tLp3m9Pt9fv8hcDEuCodCiR4aLRQJBYJwkABhHCEQg1EwiYlMFhKDiIXEpdn6iwSaSyBRKEHqCV6cnOYCmCoMKxQGyMOyMBxOIxuh1IBWJHx+AIRYKhf3hR4s9JZCA5PIFYqhSarD30OKVJANFNNaY4glTWpQWZLZZ9MZIDZbOIcw4nIliUmI6DIxkJ55s14TZYTD5c8WCwFSg0yhgwjtXLt3VGNjHN0XcvkCgHC+VE5W8NUAETkYF1bstDGYrBN3H7QnP6i+NrkihUOaQTsDLjfXp9foDLqDd0DTDA0I38QIYzCJknibAtk1TfIihKDADnzQsEJLDoy2-Y8akEaRm2mStDmrJdtmbSpW0VA05yRO4e2ZGIJlkekAEIkBAPIVwOEcxX5J0gWWENp3oWcLnnG5F3rNFWXNNJOW+Xl+PHbdqLcIA)